# Is there any editors for TeX, LaTeX and friends similar to Python Jupyter notebooks?

Tags: miktex, texlive, editors, texworks, ide

It is a while that I am using python notebooks with JupyterLab system. It is convenient indeed, far more easy for beginner user of python or people who just do not want to go deep in the code lines, than other IDEs or compilers like IDLE, Code, etc. It can compile codes line by line and block by block. It is easily editable and can be shared by colleagues to update and use. This is pretty nice for users in engineering teams. And it came my mind that similar system makes editing TeX files far more easily. It will not be traditional what-you-see is what-you-write/code the same as commercial packages.

This may be more like a feature request though, I will be happy if such notebooks exist for TeX system and you could introduce them to me.

Comment: Jupyter is able to export to TeX. So if you want to write code-oriented documents, use their markdown and export. For pure TeX such a notebook is not implementad, I fear. TeX is strictly sequential in nature, so editing as a Jupyter kernel would need an adapted TeX engine.

Comment: The extension [jupyterlab-latex](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-latex) allows to use LaTeX within JupyterLab providing an almost immediate preview if this is what you are looking for. However, if your question is how to combine ease of use with the beauty of LaTeX typesetting, then writing Markdown files and using [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) might be a good choice.

Comment: thank you @Matthias. would you mind posting your comment with more details as an answer to this question?

Comment: @TeXnician thanks indeed. how hard it is to write an interface for such purpose? because currently TeXworks has a scripting option. I think it can be developed someway.

Comment: The problem is that TeX has no REPL interface --- and it is very complex to see where something stops. I think that the best thing is to use some combination of editor-compiler to have a kind of real-time visualization. But I can be wrong, I am not at all an expert programmer.

Comment: more useful for latex is something like overleaf if you set it to continuously  compile it updates as you edit more input. But for latex it is not clear it makes sense to interleave input and output in a jupyter-like interface.